# What are some good pop-up dialog boxes for Ruby on Rails

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, user-interface, modalpopups

I want to use modal pop-up windows in our web app in Ruby on Rails.  Note that I don't want to create a new browser window, but a sub-window inside the existing webpage.  We've tried things like TinyBox, but there are issues with returning error information from inside the controller.  Any good method or tool that works well in ruby?

Comment: Do not use TinyBox.
It's undocumented and the source code is obfuscated.
You'll have trouble all the time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's also [prototype-window](http://prototype-window.xilinus.com/).

Comment: Worked with is some and its easy and powerful to use.

Answer (score 3):

I've never used it myself (not yet at least) but have you tried [RedBox](http://blog.craigambrose.com/articles/2006/08/16/redbox-a-rails-compatible-lightbox)?

Comment: Redbox looks pretty basic.  Does anyone know how to get it making some nice (transparent) borders etc like linkedin or facebook?  Would like to get something that is a littler prettier, for lack of a better word.

Answer (score 2):

I'm investigating [ModalBox](http://www.wildbit.com/labs/modalbox/) at the moment and it's looking promising.

There's a [Google Group](http://code.google.com/p/modalbox/) and [Rails plugin](http://chrischerry.name/2008/02/modalbox-confirm-plugin.html) which replaces the basic confirm popup with a modal dialog box.

Answer (score 2):

Try [TopUp](http://gettopup.com)! It is developed in a Rails application and you can get it from [GitHub](http://github.com/archan937/topup/tree/master).
Please note that it is still beta. Feedback is always welcome ;)

Answer (score 2):

[Facebox](http://github.com/defunkt/facebox/tree/master), jquery, that Github use is the best one. There is also a [prototype version](http://github.com/robertgaal/facebox-for-prototype/tree/master).

Comment: Sweet!  I always wanted to use facebox but couldn't justify loading jquery on top of prototype JUST for that.  Awesome to know there is a prototype version, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I've used [Lightbox Gone Wild](http://particletree.com/features/lightbox-gone-wild/) for a while now, though I've modified it to display a DIV or other element that's already on the page (though hidden) and then return it to it's parent when the box is closed.  I've used it make make Wizards that guide the user through a process.

Answer (score 1):

I've used [facebox_render](http://github.com/ihower/facebox_render/tree/master) for all my rails projects. It's really easy to use and provided complete helper. You can easily render html or javascript in your RESTful controller.

Answer (score 0):

I have tried several of the ones mentioned above but after twiking it a bit I found that http://www.methods.co.nz/popup/popup.html works better for me, the only problem is that you have create an error routing similar to the one Rails uses, when returning to the popup window with errors the pop up window does not have a way to handle it